# How to tell npm to install from local not git

Tags: npm, installation, doccano

I have a server without internet access but a local npm. I'm trying to install a Node.js application, and one of the modules points to github. The package is part of one of the dependencies packages.

```
{
  "name": "doccano",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "doccano is an open source annotation tools for machine learning practitioner.",
  "author": "Hironsan",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
  ...

  "dependencies": {
  ...
    "@toast-ui/vue-editor": "^1.1.1",
  ...
  }
}
```

Most packages are downloaded from local npm, but some point to github, and then I get the error:

```
npm install
...
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/seonim-ryu/Squire.git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com: Name or service not known
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128
```

I can download the repository and upload it to the server, but how can I install the github packages?

Comment: it happens because you are not logged in the github account to access to the package. You can achieve that behavior making access to github with ssh key.

Comment: Thanks @Danizavtz, but it's not that. It's because the server is in a corporate private cloud with no access to internet. I can download the package and the upload it, but I don't know how to change the referrence.